# Python - ctypes and mutable buffers

Tags: python, arguments, ctypes

I'm trying to work with ctypes, and I can't get the call to FormatMessage() to work properly.

Here's the code I have so far; I think the only issue is passing in a mutable buffer; I'm getting an ArgumentError from ctypes about lpBuffer

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD

def main():
    fm = ctypes.windll.kernel32.FormatMessageA
    fm.argtypes = [DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,DWORD,ctypes.wintypes.LPWSTR(),DWORD]

    dwFlags = DWORD(0x1000) # FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
    lpSource = DWORD(0)
    dwMessageId = DWORD(0x05)
    dwLanguageId = DWORD(0)
    #buf = ctypes.wintypes.LPWSTR()
    #lpBuffer = ctypes.byref(buf)
    lpBuffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(512)
    nSize = DWORD(512)

    res = fm(dwFlags,lpSource,dwMessageId,dwLanguageId,lpBuffer,nSize)
    print res
```

I'm getting an error on the lpBuffer argument saying it's a wrong type, but I've tried as many variations of passing in the buffer as I could think of. I've tried doing it similar to here: https://gist.github.com/CBWhiz/6135237 and setting FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER then passing in a LPWSTR() byref, I've also tried changing the argtype, pointer and casting to a variety of LPWSTR(), c_char_p, etc, but no matter what I do it keeps complaining.

What's the proper syntax to get the function to execute properly? I know ctypes can be finnicky but I haven't found anything in the documentation to resolve the issue (I know the documentation uses prototype() but I'd like to do it this way for now)

Thanks

Comment: You might consider using `win32api.FormatMessage` - it's probably easier than using `ctypes`, if you can at all.

Comment: Just a guess, what about using `create_unicode_buffer` instead of `create_string_buffer`, since these are WCHARs?

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: Is it guaranteed that `WCHAR` and `wchar_t` are the same type? On Windows, I'm pretty sure `WCHAR` is always `unsigned short` no matter what, but I believe `wchar_t` can be 32-bit depending on build settings.

Comment: Meanwhile: `DWORD(0x1000) # FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` is at least misleading, and might be your actual problem. If you or together those two flags (which are `0x0100` and `0x1000`, you get `0x1100`, not `0x1000`. If your code thinks it's passing `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` and isn't, it's not surprising things aren't working.

Comment: Finally, when you run exactly the code in that gist, does it actually fail for you? If so, what's the actual error (with traceback)? If not, show us the actual code you tried, and maybe we can tell you what you're doing differently than the correct code; otherwise, you're making us guess what you might have done differently in some code that we can't see that would return an error that we don't have any information about.

Comment: An even easier way to get the result of `FormatMessage`, for this particular use case, is to call `ctypes.WinError(dwMessageId)`, which returns you a Python exception with the message. But that obviously won't work more generally.

Comment: One more thing: Instead of trying to describe the error three different ways, please show the error and traceback. All we know is that, whatever the error is, you guessed that it means you were having a problem with a mutable buffer. It could mean something completely different, and someone else with more experience using ctypes with Windows DLLs might be able to immediately tell you what that something is.

Comment: @eryksun: I don't see `FormatMessage` anywhere in the docs or the source code. There's a `_ctypes.FormatError` that gets built on Windows… is that what you meant? If so, I'm not sure I'd rely on an undocumented function that you have to pull in from the helper extension module. (Actually, it looks like it's exposed through `ctypes` in 2.7, but not 3.3? I don't have a Windows system with both to test it on right now…)

Comment: @abarnert: My bad; I was starting right at the source yet somehow wrote the wrong name. It's actually imported into the ctypes namespace and called by `WinError`. It's there in 3.3.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion with how I worded my question; I only described methods I used to try to solve the problem to show I had at least attempted a solution. Regardless, the error was where I described it and was a type issue. I said it was a mutable buffer issue because it was in the workflow of passing a mutable buffer to ctypes. Leaving the comment in was my mistake, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the `argtypes` definition for `FormatMessageW` (note "W" for Unicode):

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

fm = ctypes.windll.kernel32.FormatMessageW
fm.argtypes = [
    wintypes.DWORD,    # dwFlags
    wintypes.LPCVOID,  # lpSource
    wintypes.DWORD,    # dwMessageId
    wintypes.DWORD,    # dwLanguageId
    wintypes.LPWSTR,   # lpBuffer
    wintypes.DWORD,    # nSize
    wintypes.LPVOID,   # Arguments (va_list *)
]

FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = 0x100  
FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x1000
```

If `FormatMessage` allocates the buffer, you have to instead pass a reference to `lpBuffer`. Just `cast` the reference to get around the `TypeError`. Also, remember to call `kernel32.LocalFree` to free the buffer:

```
def main():
    dwFlags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
    lpSource = None
    dwMessageId = 5
    dwLanguageId = 0    
    lpBuffer = wintypes.LPWSTR()
    nSize = 0  # minimum size
    Arguments = None

    if not fm(dwFlags, lpSource, dwMessageId, dwLanguageId, 
              ctypes.cast(ctypes.byref(lpBuffer), wintypes.LPWSTR), 
              nSize, Arguments):
        raise ctypes.WinError()

    msg = lpBuffer.value.rstrip()
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.LocalFree(lpBuffer)

    return msg
```

Comment: This code is effectively the same as [the gist](https://gist.github.com/CBWhiz/6135237) that he linked to, and claims to have tried. You haven't fixed or explained any bugs in that code (because, as far as I can tell, that code works, exactly the same as yours). So, whatever the OP's problem is, I'm not sure this really solves it, unless the plan is to keep throwing examples at him until he copies and pastes one without breaking it.

Comment: @abarnert: The code in the question is incorrectly using `FormatMessageA` with unicode data types. It also has an incomplete `argtypes` (it's `stdcall` so you need all args). The pointer needs to be passed `byref` to fill in the address of the allocated buffer, which requires a `cast`, and without `LocalFree` it's a memory leak. Yes this answer is similar to the gist, but that isn't using `argtypes`, so it doesn't have the `TypeError` problem.

Comment: The point is that the code from the gist he linked to, [here](https://gist.github.com/CBWhiz/6135237), uses `FormatMessageW`, and uses `byref` properly, and so on, and if you run that code, it works. Giving him another version that also works is nice, but I don't think it's enough to help him understand what he did wrong. (This isn't a criticism of you—I don't think there's _any_ way to help him understand what he did wrong if he won't show us what he actually did.)

Comment: @abarnert Fewmitz said "I'm getting an error on the lpBuffer argument saying it's a wrong type". That comes from defining `argtypes` to `LPWSTR`, which is fine for its normal use where the caller allocates the buffer. However, it requires a `cast` if you use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` and thus pass a reference to the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I didn't see anything on MSDN or the ctypes reference that stated my parameters were incompatible with Unicode. Regardless taking out the args and doing it as described here solved the problem.

Comment: @eryksun: He also said he tried using the code from the gist, and described half a dozen other things he tried, all of which make sense, but he clearly didn't do them correctly.

Comment: @Fewmitz: The problem isn't that your parameters are "incompatible with Unicode", it's that you're mixing Unicode (or, really, WCHAR) and bytes, and secondarily that you seem to be confused about whether you're passing `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` or not. There are a number of ways to fix it—use `FormatMessageA` and `LPSTR`, use `create_unicode_buffer` instead of `create_string_buffer`, remove the buffer and use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER` and add the `byref` and `cast`… but you have to be consistent.